# Exclude 'nil' row from ActiveRecord query with a HAVING clause where no results are returned

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm building a series of methods in a model to use as scopes. When one of these uses a having clause and that query returns no results, I get an instance of the model returned where all fields are nil, and that breaks most code I'd like to use these scopes in.

The below is a highly simplified example to demonstrate my issue.

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :components

  def without_components
    joins(:components).group('widgets.id')having('COUNT(components.id) = 0')
  end

  def without_components_and_remove_nil
    without_components.select{|i| i.id} # Return objects where i.id is not nil
  end
end
```

Calling `Widget.without_components` if all Widgets have components assigned returns the non-desirable:

`[{id: nil, name: nil, user_id: nil}]`

But if I call `Widget.without_components_and_remove_nil` it converts the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object that would be returned into an `Array`, so I can't chain it with other scopes as I need to do.

Is there a way of changing the scopes so that either the nil row is excluded if it appears, or is there a modification that could be made to my ActiveRecord query to allow for this to work?

Comment: How on earth did you manage to get a record with no id into your database?

Comment: It's not a record with no ID, it's a result of the SQL generated. I'm using MySQL, don't know if that makes a difference, but when there is a HAVING clause that returns no results, it's MySQL that returns the row of all nil's; it's not actually in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues I needed to resolve to get that scope working; one not related to my original question, though the scope I presented above wouldn't have been fixed without it:

- First, and directly dealing with the question at hand, since Rails 3.1 you can do this:

.

```
Widget.where(id: Widget.joins(:components).group('widgets.id').having('COUNT(components.id)'))
```

- Second, the `joins(:components)` part of it wasn't going to work with the `having('COUNT(components.id = 0)')` because `joins` performs an inner join, thus there would never be any results for that query. I had to replace the `joins` with `joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN components ON components.widget_id = widgets.id")`.